# Wpf Geometry.Transform Property can be TransformCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometry.transform?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Media.Geometry.Transform)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.2)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.5) it is written:

> Property Value
>
> Transform
>
> The transformation applied to the Geometry.
> **Note that this value may be a single Transform or a
> TransformCollection cast as a Transform.**

But my code gives an error:

```
    myGeometry.Transform = (Transform)new TransformCollection(new Transform[] {
        new TranslateTransform(33, 22),
        new ScaleTransform(2, 1)
    });
```

> Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Media.TransformCollection' to 'System.Windows.Media.Transform'

Anyone have an explanation? Maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransformCollection` is not a derived type of `Transform`, also there is no explicit operator converting it to the type of `Transform`. You should do it like this:

```
myGeometry.Transform = new TransformGroup
{
    Children = new TransformCollection
    {
        new TranslateTransform(33, 22),
        new ScaleTransform(2, 1)
    }
};
```

Or simpler, without creating a new TransformCollection instance at all:

```
var transform = new TransformGroup();
transform.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(33, 22));
transform.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(2, 1));
myGeometry.Transform = transform;
```